# The connections between Kolmogorov complexity and mathematical logic

Tags: lo.logic, big-list, kolmogorov-complexity

We know that Kolmogorov Cmplexity (KC) has connections to mathematical logic since it can be used to prove the Gödel incompleteness results (Chaitin's Theorem and [Kritchman-Raz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4974)). Are there any other striking application of Kolmogorov complexity to mathematical logic (outside KC itself of course)?

Relatively simple examples like the ones I mentioned are preferred, but more complicated illustrations are also very welcome!

(This is cross posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742524/the-connection-between-kolmogorov-complexity-and-mathematical-logic), because I wasn't getting any useful replies there)

Answer (score 4):

*Four pointers to the literature from the last 25 years on applications of Kolmogorov complexity to mathematical logic:*

[Applications of Kolmogorov complexity to computable model theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27588584) (2007).

> In this paper we answer the following well-known open question in
> computable model theory. Does there exist a computable not
> ℵ$_0$-categorical saturated structure with a unique computable
> isomorphism type? Our answer is affirmative and uses a construction
> based on Kolmogorov complexity.

[Logical operations and Kolmogorov complexity](http://www.lirmm.fr/~ashen/mathtext/intuit99/final.pdf) (2002).

> Conditional Kolmogorov complexity can be understood as the complexity
> of the problem $Y\rightarrow X$, where $Y$ is the problem “construct
> $y$” and $X$ is the problem “construct  $x$”. Other logical operations
> ($\wedge,\lor,\leftrightarrow$) can be interpreted in a similar way,
> extending Kolmogorov interpretation of intuitionistic logic and Kleene
> realizability.

[The Kolmogorov expression complexity of logics](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Kolmogorov-Expression-Complexity-of-Logics-Tyszkiewicz/2fbaf57dcb58ac4c076c33fcaa5b21c59df35e08) (1997).

> We introduce the Kolmogorov variant of Vardi's expression complexity.
> We define it by considering the value of the Kolmogorov complexity
> $C(L[{\cal A}])$ of the infinite string $L[{\cal A}]$ of all truth
> values of sentences of $L$ in ${\cal A}$. The higher is this value,
> the more expressive is the logic $L$ in ${\cal A}$.

[Kolmogorov complexity and the second incompleteness theorem](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0912-3.pdf) (1995).

> It is well known that Kolmogorov complexity has a close relation with
> Gödel’s first incompleteness theorem. In this paper, we give a new
> formulation of the first incompleteness theorem in terms of Kolmogorov
> complexity, that is a generalization of Kolmogorov’s theorem, and
> derive a semantic proof of the second incompleteness theorem from it.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. So before Chaitin's work in '71, were there any significant applications of KC to mathematical logic that you are aware of?